# How to use WindowsDriver in Appium to wait for an element to load before clicking on it

Tags: appium

I am using Appium with Windows Driver to test my Windows based Dot net application. I am trying to click on a link through my automation tests.
When my automation test is running, then its not waiting till my element(link) in the application is loaded/visible . Because of this my test fails.
Is there a WinAppDriver /Windows Driver waittillElementisvisible property (like how we have in Selenium Webdriver) so that it waits till the element is loaded ?
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 do
        {
        WebElement element =  ((WindowsDriver) webDriver).findElement(by, using);
        try {
                if ( element != null ) {
                    element.click();
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    return;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.debug("Couldnt find element using byType " +by + " locator " + using + " because of exception" + e.getMessage());
                attempt++;
                try {

                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    logger.debug("Exception while sleeping " + e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        } while (attempt < 5 );
        throw new WebDriverException("Couldnt find element using byType " +by + " locator " + using );
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am using Windows Driver and not WebDriver as my application is a desktop based application and afaik it doesnt support Wait / FluentWait , how its supported for WebDriver (WebDriverWait).

Comment: I have edited my answer, can you please check if it's working? I found this solution  [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/364)

Comment: This wont work since I dont have WebElement but WindowsElement and also  "By" locator is not implemented in WinAppDriver . i want something to work with WinApp driver implmentation for Windows element not web.